# Overhead - Calling C++ function from C#

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling

I am calling two C++ functions from C#. While doing that in a iteration for around 1 million call i am seeing a overhead of about 30%.

C++ function :

```
EXTERN_C void STDAPICALLTYPE FunctionA(UINT_PTR mathId)
{
    ...
    ...
}
```

In my C# assembly dll as :

```
[DllImport("CPlusPlus.dll")]
    public static extern void FunctionA([In] IntPtr mathID);
```

Called from function as below:

```
 public static void HelpingFunction([In]UInt64 mathID)
    {
        FunctionA((IntPtr)mathID);
    }
```

This way of implementation is creating more overhead when the "HelpingFunction" is called more than a million times.

Can someone give me other ideas so that the overhead can be reduced? What are the other ways to call a C++ function from a C# assembly?

Comment: Very hard to know how you could improve this, because we cannot see the insides of `FunctionA`.

Comment: You might also consider writing a CLI wrapper around the loop, so your overhead is reduced from "millions" of calls to just a few.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to add `SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute`.

> Allows managed code to call into unmanaged code without a stack walk.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.suppressunmanagedcodesecurityattribute.aspx

But on p/invoke call always will be fixed cost overhead:

> PInvoke has an overhead of between 10 and 30 x86 instructions per
>   call. In addition to this fixed cost, marshaling creates additional
>   overhead. There is no marshaling cost between blittable types that
>   have the same representation in managed and unmanaged code. For
>   example, there is no cost to translate between int and Int32.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx

Comment: do u mean adding [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity] above the function "HelpingFunction(..)" definition ?

Comment: no, above DllImport or like this [DllImport("CPlusPlus.dll"), System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]